# Create google map failed after internet reconnected

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I am creating google map on hybrid app and network suddenly disconnet, the google map show nothing after network has been reconnected. I got a error message as below and try to reload google map javascript again. Sometimes the map was created success but always failed. Is there any solution for this problem?

`GET http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/zh_tw/mapfiles/api-3/16/2/%7Bcommon,map%7D.js`

```
net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED %7Bmain,places%7D.js:10
```

`GET http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/zh_tw/mapfiles/api-3/16/2/%7Butil,stats%7D.js`

```
net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED %7Bmain,places%7D.js:10

watchPositionError 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Sometimes the map was created success but always failed."?

Answer (score 0):

I know it can be annoying to think about, but at some point you just have to put it out of your head, and an important thing to take note of is sometimes the user will enter into situations where your app doesn't work exactly as you want it to, and it's out of your control, for example if the user disconnects the internet.

Another example of this would be if the user doesn't support cookies, or if they don't support javascript. As a developer, you won't always be working with the resources you need to build software for every person on every platform and in every scenario. Sure google has the ability to handle internet disconnect/reconnect in google drive, syncing up to the server when a connection is re-established, and Twitter has a mobile site that supports users who don't have javascript. As a developer you will have to make a judgement call on what is and what isn't a must-have feature. I'm guessing this isn't a must-have feature.